# What Javascript framework integrates well with Grails?

Tags: java, javascript, grails, groovy, javascript-framework

Most of the applications that we produce for the front end uses Grails and we love it to death but we are exploring Javascript frameworks such as backbone.js, ember.js for templating, reusability. We are comfortable and familiar with json and would like to know what are some experiences and recommendations for a Javascript framework that plays nice with Grails.

Would like to understand the evaluation criteria, cost of implementation and learning curve involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`backbone` is fully flexible framework, and can be used with grails without any pain (and I've used it, with Grails). I compatible with most js libs (jquery, zepto, etc), with most client side templating languages, etc.

`ember` as I see is more high level, but have some constraints for your app architecture, for example it works best when you're using `handlebars`. So you need to learn a new templating language, at least. And I'm not sure that there is server-side renderers for handlebars (for case when you want to render page on server side as well)

Comment: Have you any other experiences with other js Frameworks on Grails? Essentially what I'm trying to figure out is which ones are well supported and has a large enough community to support its adoption.

Comment: Maybe `GWT` also, and `jQuery`, but i'm sure it's not what you're asking. If you're asking about *js mvc framework*, then `backbone` looks one of most popular

Comment: Yeah I am looking for js mvc, I have done a lot of jQuery and ProtoType but as the project grows, it gets more fragmented. For the sake of maintainability I am hoping to consolidate all that front end template. Thanks for your help.

Comment: BTW, when using Backbone.js with Grails, be aware that underscore.js template escape characters `<%= %>`, need to be changed because they conflict with GSP/JSP.